# In a Rails WHERE LIKE query, what does the percent sign mean?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, search, model

In a simple search like this:

```
find.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

I understand that `#{search}` is just string interpolation. What do the `%` symbols do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The percent sign `%` is a [wildcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) in SQL that matches zero or more characters. Thus, if `search` is `"hello"`, it would match strings in the database such as `"hello"`, `"hello world"`, `"well hello world"`, etc.

Note that this is a part of SQL and is not specific to Rails/ActiveRecord. The queries it can be used with, and the precise behavior of `LIKE`, differ based on SQL dialect (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

```
search = 'something'
find.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

In your DB it will be interpreted  as

```
SELECT <fields> FROM finds WHERE name LIKE '%something%';
```

Answer (score 1):

The percent sign in a like query is a wildcard. So, your query is saying "anything, followed by whatever is in the `search` variable, followed by anything".

Note that this use of the percent sign is part of the SQL standard and not specific to Rails or ActiveRecord. Also be aware that this kind of search does note scale well -- your SQL db will be forced to scan through every row in the table trying to find matches rather than being able to rely on an index.